# Is the use of "former" with astronauts really necessary?

Tags: astronauts, terminology

When reading space exploration related articles, I often come across the use of *"former"* to classify astronaut's status. NASA even puts *"former astronauts"* as a separate classification [on their pages](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/astrobio_former.html), describing the status as:

> Former astronauts are those who have left NASA, including those who
>   are deceased.

This use of *"former"* seems a bit awkward to me, especially since NASA doesn't really hold any exclusive rights to the use of the word *"astronaut"*. For example, we usually don't call [Ernest Shackleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Shackleton) a *"former explorer"*. Deceased yes, but he was a polar explorer. So my question is:

**Is *"astronaut"* an official title, a job description, or a life achievement? Should we use the word *"former"*, and when would it be appropriate to use it?**

Comment: I believe when NASA uses "former astronauts" in such cases, it is a shortened form of "former employees who are/were astronauts".

Comment: @called2voyage My question is in essence, if "former astronaut" is an official title/status? If it's a shorthand for "former NASA astronaut", then surely even shorter version would be "astronaut", so why include "former" so often in texts? There must be some official reason for it, a bit like adding "retired" at the end of some other job titles, perhaps?

Comment: I would imagine so.

Comment: Just as clarification, with "when would it be appropriate to use it" I mean, for example, would that be a formal salutation?

Comment: [This usage](http://www.nasa.gov/about/whats_next.html#.UoaA_9ykqrw) is problematic for my conjecture.

Comment: It seems that NASA defines "astronaut" as someone who currently holds the *job title* of astronaut: "The question of exactly who is an astronaut is more involved, at least in the U.S. Within NASA, 'astronaut' is a job description for those individuals selected to be members of the Astronaut Corps at the Johnson Space Center in Houston. Once an astronaut candidate completes training, he or she becomes a career astronaut, even before their first space flight." [Source](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/news/X-Press/stories/2005/102105_Schneider.html)

Comment: I think @called2voyage nailed it. And with Astronaut as a job description, that other usage question (what do we call Russian astronauts) solves itself as well: we can call them all astronauts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the use of 'former' is representative of both their employment status and their licensing/qualification status.  For instance a internet search for "former pilot" (including quotes) finds several references people who are either former employees and/or who have lost their license.

John Glenn is referenced as a "former astronaut" until the [STS-95 mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-95), where he re-qualifies and is considered a current or active astronaut.  Because his qualification for the 1998 flight is now expired he is again a ["former"](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/glenn-j.html).